# How to verify Websocket connection has data to read or not through jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to mimic a scenario on jmeter that I will send some Send request and based on the user the responses will be received on websocket.

As the count of received responses are changing i cann't use the same number of read samplers.

Read sampler
[image]

The output after few iterations (different user login)
[image]

Instead of give the Loop controller with definite loop count, if we check the connection status and run the read sampler then it will not fail.

Can help me how to implement that in Jmeter?

Thanks
Sarada

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to read [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/)?

> **Fragmentation**
>
> WebSocket messages may be fragmented into several frames. In such cases the first frame is an ordinary text or binary frame, but it will have the `final` bit cleared. The succeeding frames will be continuation frames (whether they are text or binary is inferred by the first frame) and the last continuation frame will have the `final` bit set. The plugin supports continuation frames, but as the plugin is frame-oriented, you'll have to read them yourself. In cases where the number of fragments is known beforehand, this is as easy as adding an extra WebSocketReadSampler for each continuation frame you expect. If the number of continuation frames is not known, you need to create a loop to read all the continuation frames. For this purpose, the plugin provides a new JMeter variable called websocket.last_frame_final that indicates whether the last frame read was final. This enables you to write a simple loop with a standard JMeter While Controller; use the expression `${__javaScript(! ${websocket.last_frame_final},)}` as condition. With a JMeter If Controller, the condition can be simplified to ! ${websocket.last_frame_final} because that controller automatically interprets the condition as JavaScript. See the sample [Read continuation frames.jmx](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/Read%20continuation%20frames.jmx) test plan for examples of using the While or the If controller to read continuation frames.
>
> If you are unsure whether continuation frames are sent by your server or how much, switch on debug logging: samplers reading a frame will log whether the received frame is a "normal" single frame, a non-final frame (i.e. 1st fragment), a continuation frame or a final continuation frame (last fragment).

More information:

- [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter)
- [Logging and error messages](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Comment: Thanks for reply  Ivan, I tried the above solution with while loop but my script is not going to while loop itself, i used the condtion ${__javaScript(! ${websocket.last_frame_final},)} in the while loop. Is there can be any other reason

Comment: I used Debug sampler and found that websocket.last_frame_final=true, thats why it is not going inside the while loop but there are some more received responses available how to know about that received response count and initialize the loop count to that?, Thanks